# How to concatenate two collections of user-defined class

Tags: python

I'm having:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "Collection") to list.
```

I am trying to override the method `__add__` in my `Collection` class
to concatenate two collections or a collection
with an `iterable` object.

My class definition looks like this:

```
class Collection(object):
"""
Collection class definition
"""
    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        """
        Constructor of the class.
        :param iterable: any iterable object except for dictionary
        """
        self.iterable = () if iterable is None else iterable
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.iterable + other

    def append(self, *elements):
        """
        The method append return a new Collection with the new elements appended to the end.
        :param elements: The new elements to append
        :return: A new Collection instance with the new elements appended to its end.
        """
        return Collection(self.iterable + (type(self.iterable))(elements))
```

I am required to create an object-oriented collection. The object should be immutable, meaning that each method should
return a new instance of the class and not alter the internal data.

I tried type casting `other` and `self.iterable` to lists, but with no luck.
Let's say I have:

```
c1 = Collection([1,2,3,4])
c2 = Collection([1,2,3,4])
iterable = 'hello'
print(c1 + c2 + iterable)
# => Collecton(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,'h','e','l','l','o')
```

1) Do I even met the requirements of making an immutable type?

2) How can I fix the type differences?

As an example, I have added the custom method `append`, which work well with typecasting.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Your add method assumes that there's an add method---the add method has to define what `+` means, but your definition just again uses `+`. So you need to return some collection that includes all the stuff in both collections.

Comment: If i override the add method, may i call different class methods? also how does append work when i didn't define the add method correct?

Comment: Right, you'll need to define the add method before you can use the append method correctly. It's totally fine to call other methods within a method, though. In this case, the `+` in your append method will call the `__add__` method. I realize this is an assignment or similar so you have to implement it, but just for reference, I wouldn't have an `append` method on an immutable object, as the name `append` implies a mutation of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming finite iterables, you could use [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain


class Collection(object):
    """Collection class definition"""

    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        """
        Constructor of the class.
        :param iterable: any iterable object except for dictionary
        """
        self.iterable = () if iterable is None else iterable

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Collection(chain.from_iterable([self.iterable, other]))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Collection({})'.format(list(self.iterable))

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.iterable


c1 = Collection([1,2,3,4])
c2 = Collection([1,2,3,4])
iterable = 'hello'
print(c1 + c2 + iterable)
```

**Output**

```
Collection([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'])
```

Comment: Solid and clean approach.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderReynolds